# Typescript Introspection Type to String

Tags: typescript, reflection, introspection, typescript-generics

Is there a way to get to the type of a class member as string?

```
class A {
   b: string & MinSize<5>
}
```

I wanted the `MinSize` in a string and `5` in a number, is this possible?
The idea is to use some validation of `b` and find the validator for `MinSize` in a map. (Probably not because this gets erased after compilation).

With an additional annotation, this would work but looks ugly.

```
class A {
   @MinSize(5)
   b: string & MinSize<5>
}
```

Other ideas appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have here makes sense. `MinSize` would be some generic and you want the generic parameter to be a literal value of a string or number? That's usually the job of a function. Moreover, what's `string & MinSize<5>` supposed to be? What is the intersection between a string and a number?

Comment: I wrote some explainations here https://github.com/sveseme/taghiro